# Is it possible to disable manual trigger for release pipeline in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have configured a release pipeline in my environment in a way as dev -> test -> uat -> prod stages.

My query is whether its possible to disable the manual deployment happens to individual stages like we should not be able to deploy to uat until the test stage is completed.

Right now we will be able to manually run the uat stage even if the dev and test stage is not completed or we haven't  run those stages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we cannot disable manual trigger for particular stage in release pipeline, but we can [control deployments using approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/approvals?view=azure-devops), so you can set a pre-deployment approval for uat stage, and then deny broken deployment. Also we can set Gate for stage, see: [Release gates and approvals overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/?view=azure-devops) for details.

Comment: Hi Sebastian, does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Edward, did something change on that topic? Or is it possiblr to exclude certain branches from manual triggers?